# django queryset filter out the objects with same values

Tags: python, regex

I have

```
s = "[[[a_12]]] [[[|]]]"
```

I need to grab `a_12` from s with regexp which should not parse `[[[|]]]`.

I tried:

```
re.search(r'\[\[\[ [^\]]+ \]\]\]', s).group()
```

but it grabs `[[[|]]]` also if I put it into first place. I am so bad at regexp, can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you please clearly define what exactly you want to capture?

Comment: @thefourtheye I edited the question, i hope it is clearer now

Comment: @doniyor in what basis, you don't want to capture `|`. Is this because `|` is a non-word character?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am using ``|`` for delimeters, thats why i need ``[[[|]]]`` later for parsing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore `|` by adding `|` into the negated class

**Test**

```
>>> s = "[[[a_12]]] [[[|]]]"
>>> re.search(r'\[\[\[[^\]\|]+\]\]\]', s).group()
'[[[a_12]]]'

>>> s = "[[[|]]] [[[a_12]]]"
>>> re.search(r'\[\[\[[^\]\|]+\]\]\]', s).group()
'[[[a_12]]]'
```

- `[^\]\|]` matches anything other than `|` or `]`

Comment: perfect, this is what i wanted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To capture only the word characters present inbetween `[[[]]]`.

```
>>> s = "[[[a_12]]] [[[|]]]"
>>> re.findall(r'\[\[\[(\w+)]]]', s)
['a_12']
```